# @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions lint rule

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

adding

```
"@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": [
    2,
    {
        "ignoreRhs": true,
        "allow-boolean-or-undefined": true
    }
],
```

to my eslintrc.json gives me the following error Error: .eslintrc.json:
    Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions" is invalid:
    Value {"ignoreRhs":true,"allow-boolean-or-undefined":true} should NOT have additional properties.

What is the right way to mention options for this rule?

Answer (score 4):

On **eslintrc rules** you can try the configuration below and eslint will stop notifying you.

```
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": 0
  }
```

Comment: This will turn off the rule

Answer (score 1):

The allow-boolean-or-undefined doesn't exist for this rule on ESLint, the option equivalent is the allowNullable.
The correct syntax is:

```
'@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions': ['error', { allowNullable: true, ignoreRhs: true }],
```

You can check the doc for the rule [strict-boolean-expressions documentation](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md)